# How do I get the values of a 2d array returned and then accessed in another class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, return-value

I am trying to be able to use the "row" and "col" variable to book a seat, however after I return the values  and then go back to the other class where I called the method I can't use the values of the returned "seat[row][col]".

EDIT: Sorry about the poorly worded question. For example, if the returned value was seats[0][4], I want to be able to use the indices of the seat: row:0 and col:4 in the first set of code which I can book a seat from these values. My problem is currently when it goes back to the first method, it is booking the seat: seats[0][0] instead of e.g. seats[0][4](should have been returned) which would be the correct seat to book. How can I access the the returned values?
SeatT has the type of seat which is an Enum either Wall, middle, or aisle

Where I am calling the method to return a free seat from:

```
    for(int row = 0;row<journey.floor.getLastRow(journey);++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0;col<journey.floor.getLastCol(journey);++col)
        {
            if(journey.floor.findAvailableSeat(type)!=null)
            {
                seats[row][col].booked = true;      
                System.out.println(seats[row][col].toString());
                return seats[row][col];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where I am finding which is an available seat:

```
public Seat findAvailableSeat(SeatT type)
{
    for(int row = 0; row<lastRow;++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col<lastCol;++col)
        {
            if(seats[row][col].getFirstClass() == false && seats[row][col].booked == false && seats[row][col].type == type)
            {
                return seats[row][col];
            }
            else if(seats[row][col].getFirstClass() == false && seats[row][col].booked == false)
            {
                return seats[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I have tried saving the returned value of the called method into another variable e.g. Seats[][] seat = findAvailableSeats(), but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use which values?

Comment: It doesn;t seem like you are passing row and col variable, or if you are (inside SeatT) you are not extracting it from there. Please specify what is SeatT.

Comment: The first function doesn't iterate and terminates after the first element. Thats bacause of else {return null;} which will exit the function. Remove the return and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is very poorly written. We don't know what Seat is, we don't know what "doesn't work for me" is. The only thing apparent is that you lack a basic understanding of the technology you are using. Please read-up on some basic Java tutorials and also please read before you post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JoeC row and col e.g. seats[0][4] as it has the seats of the available seat, I want to use this in the other method so I can "book" it.

Comment: And where is `seats` defined?  (This is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @dev8080 Nope, I'm not inside SeatT. SeatT is an enum for type of seat: wall, aisle, middle but I don't think it was relevant to the question.

Comment: @Caiz Ok  I read that wrong. What is Seat, I meant to ask, not SeatT.